# Date Manipulation to output the same date

Tags: excel, date, row, creation

Good day!

Using Excel and would like to multiply a date by a value to create new a row with the same date

Example;

before

```
Column A 
27-OCT-19
```

execution

```
Column A          Column b
27-OCT-19    X        4
```

output

```
Column A
27-OCT-19
27-OCT-19
27-OCT-19
27-OCT-19
```

I've looked around and it seems that people use Visual Basic - However, I can't use Visual Basic due to permission issues on my network.

Comment: So, for example, if cell `A2` has the value of `27-OCT-19` you would like a formula for cell `B2` that outputs the text value: `27-OCT-19 27-OCT-19 27-OCT-19 27-OCT-19`?

Answer (score 1):

If your first date begins in cell `A2` then enter this formula in cell `B2`:

```
=MID(REPT(TEXT(A2," dd-mmm-yy"),4),2,99)
```

Now copy the formula downward as far as you need.

---

Based on your revised question, the following should work.

With your `reference date` in cell `A2` and your `multiply value` in cell `B2` enter this formula in cell `A3`:

```
=IF((ROW()-ROW($A$2))<$B$2,$A$2,"")
```

Now copy the formula downward as far as you need.

Comment: My post some how got messed up. You did great based on the format above. I need it to create new cells within the column so A3 = 5 OCT 20 x 4                                           = A3, A4, A5, A6 = 5 OCT 20

Comment: @RoyZacharias I updated my answer to work with your revised question. Is this update what you needed?

Comment: You are welcome. Please accept my answer. When you do a large green check-mark is displayed.

Answer (score 0):

If you have Excel O365 with the `SEQUENCE` function, you can use:

```
A3: =TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(REPT(TEXT($A$2,"dd-mmm-yy "),B2)," ",REPT(" ",99)),IF(SEQUENCE(B2)=1,1,(SEQUENCE(B2)-1)*99),99))
```

and the results will `SPILL` down as far as required.

[image]